# append in jquery works sometimes and sometimes doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append a span element in a div tag using the below code .

```
 $( document ).ready(function() { 
$(".rocketchat-widget").append("<span class='tooltiptext'>Chat button</span>");
});
```

sometimes it works and adds the element.

[image]

But sometimes it doesn't load the element.
[image]

I am new to jquery so any help would be appreciable

Thank you

Comment: This is standard behaviour. Amendments you make to the DOM during the page's life are not maintained on successive page loads, unless you specifically write code to do it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan But it is adding the element when document completely loads so shouldn't it add tyhe element on successive reloads also

Comment: You've now edited the question. Your original question was asking why the element disappears when you reloaded the page...?

Comment: How is `rocketchat` getting added to the page? You need to ensure that `.rocket-chat-widget` exists before you try to append.

Comment: it looks like it should work to me, can you show more of your code?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes I noticed that it was not loading theelement on first loads also sometimes

Comment: @Shahzad why don't you create jsfiddle (demo) to prove that it doesn't work?

Comment: @bhagwanparge ok creating

Comment: @bhagwanparge I am unable to recreate it in the jsfiddle. By adding the js and css it turns the chat icon into a circular icon but it is not showing I needed to add a tooltip to that icon but still here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/shahzad285/xpvt214o/788855/      . If it can give you any idea

Comment: @MaxBaldwin Rocket chat is getting added in the IFrame using some script

Comment: so you want to append something in the iframe...which gets loaded after some time, right?

Comment: @bhagwanparge yes\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is what you want, op (shahzad) was including third party widget on page load, as it is a third party widget sometimes it will load early or later, so, needed below code,

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 
    $(document).on("click", "[data-state=closed]" , function() { $(this).data('state', 'opened').attr('data-state', 'opened'); }); 

    myVar = setInterval(function() {
        if($(".rocketchat-widget").length){
            $(".rocketchat-widget").append("<span class='tooltiptext'>Chat button</span>");
            clearInterval(myVar);
        }        
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Please take a moment to edit your question and explain what you've done differently (and perhaps *why*). A "spot-the-difference" answer is very rarely a "good" answer. Additionally, no need to encourage other users to upvote - comments should remain helpful and constructive :)

Comment: @bhagwanparge I am out of the office will check it tommorow and let know if it works